# Focus DIV out of a DIV array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a to create an array of text boxes and every-time one is created is supposed to be focused.  This is my not working code. any help would be much appreciated. thanks.

```
var emails = new Array();       
var count = 0;  

//function to add more extra emails     
$('#additional_emails').focus(function() {

   emails[count] = '<input type="text" size="30" id="email_list'+ count + '" value    ="'+count+'" /><br>';

   $('#here_emails').append( $(emails[count]).focus() );

   count++;
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Try focusing the element *after* it has been added to the page:

```
$(emails[count])
    .appendTo($('#here_emails'))
    .focus();
```

**Bonus:**

1. To define an empty array, you can use the array literal `[]`: `var emails = [];`
2. To add new items to an array, you can use the `push()` method instead of incrementing your own index variable: `emails.push(...);`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is my first time usin a forum you have saved me lots of confusion. Many many thanks